Verify if formula is tautology in Intuitionistic logic
I have following formula:
$\left( A \rightarrow (B \vee \neg B) \right) \vee \left( \neg A \rightarrow (B \vee \neg B) \right)$
I know a method to veify that formula is not a tautology in intuitionistic logic that uses topological spaces but not sure what else I can use... I also know that formula $(B \vee \neg B)$ isn't tautology in intuitionistic logic

Set $B := ⊤$, then it is equivalent to $A ∨ ¬A$. (There was an answer that said “set $A := ⊤$” and was probably meant like this, sorry for downvoting it without realizing it could be easily fixed.)

@JeanAbouSamra If B is $\top$, then $B \lor \lnot B$ is $\top$ too. $A \to \top$ is true regardless of what $A$ is. I beginning to think there isn't an easy resolution to this.

@JeanAbouSamra By the way, no worries about the downvote. It was a wrong answer and deleting undoes any negative reputation

@S.C. can I build Truth Table for 3 values (T, F, U) to prove?

@leeeeeeeeess That might disprove it (it won't) but there aren't any finite complete semantics of intuitionistic logic so checking any finite model won't be enough to prove it.

@S.C. do you think this is tautology?

@S.C.  How to correct a mistake and then do exactly the same mistake…

@leeeeeeeeess Coq confirms it's not a tautology (running the tauto tactic fails) but I guess you have to reach out for a semantics of propositional calculus to prove it.

Comment: There's more or less well-studied "bounded depth principles", that are not provable in intuitionistic logic. The first one being $A\lor\big(A\to(B\lor \neg B)\big)$. Roughly, it says that every proposition $A$ either holds true or "is sorta explosive" to the extent that it implies excluded middle for propositions $B$. So that's a weakening of the classical idea of every $A$ either holding true or being just false. By the principle of explosion, that principle implies your principle. So I think your principle is quite weak.

There is a Kripke countermodel to this, and thus it is not provable in intuitionistic logic.
\begin{matrix}
  W_{12} &&&& W_{22} \\
  \huge|&&&& \huge| \\
  W_{11} &&&& W_{21}\\
  &\huge\diagdown && \huge\diagup \\
  &&W_0
\end{matrix}
(in this diagram, lower worlds are less than higher worlds and we take the transitive and reflexive closure of this Hasse diagram).
Just a point of terminology here: we'll say that $\varphi$ is true at $W$ if $W \vdash \varphi$ and say it's false at $W$ if $W \not\vdash \varphi$. A proposition being false at a world doesn't necessarily mean that the negation of that proposition is true. It's possible to have neither $W \vdash \varphi$ nor $W \vdash \lnot \varphi$.
$A$ is taken to be true at $W_{11}$ and $W_{12}$, while $B$ is taken to be true at $W_{12}$ and $W_{22}$.
Then $(A \to (B \lor \lnot B)) \lor (\lnot A \to (B \lor \lnot B)$ is false at $W_0$. This is because from $W_0$, there is a higher world where $A$ is true but $B \lor \lnot B$ is false, namely $W_{11}$ and there is a higher world where $\lnot A$ is true, but $B \lor \lnot B$ is false (namely $W_{21}$). $\lnot A$ is true at $W_{21}$ because $A$ is false at that world and all higher ones.
$B \lor \lnot B$ is false at $W_{11}$ and $W_{21}$ because $B$ isn't true at those worlds but there is a higher world from those worlds where it is true, so $\lnot B$ isn't true either.

One decision procedure for Intuitionistic propositional calculus is Gentzen’s LJ sequent calculus. If a tree terminates without reaching identity ($A \vdash A$) on all of the branches, then the formula is not an Intuitionistic tautology.
We can see pretty plainly by the $\lor$ right rules that the only way to proceed to a proof of the formula in question is by proving either $\vdash A \to (B \lor \neg B)$ or $\vdash \neg A \to (B \lor \neg B)$. Since neither of those formulas are tautologies, it is clear that the tree will not terminate with identity at the end of every brance.
For example, choosing the left branch of the tree for the formula in question, we get an open tree as follows:
$\cfrac{\cfrac{A \vdash B}{A \vdash (B \lor \neg B)}\lor R_1}{\vdash A \to (B \lor \neg B)}\to R$.
All you have to do is systematically check each rule that can be done to a given sequent, and if you cannot simplify it down to identity, the formula is invalid. So, the above example constitutes only one case of a full counter-example.
Non-syntactic methods also exist, such as arguments from Kripke Semantics or Heyting Algebra.

The main takeaway is to become familiar with how Intuitionistic proofs are constructed to see if there is a proof of the formula by trying to see what else would have to be provable. In this case, we needed $(B \lor \neg B)$ to be provable, which it is not.

Good point; more concisely, this is an appeal to the disjunction property of intuitionistic logic.

@JeanAbouSamra not just the disjunction property, but rather the way the rules are designed for system LJ in particular. But yes, this specific instance boils down to the disjunction property, even though you could use LJ to check the validity of any formula.
